# Question about select command execution in a script

Tags: python, maya

How to execute the `cmds.select` before `confirmDialog`

```
cmds.select(clear=True)
lightType =['aiAreaLight']
selLight=cmds.ls(lights=True, visible = True, type= lightType )
cmds.select(selLight)

answer = cmds.confirmDialog()
```

I've a stupid problem in a script for Maya.

When I try to select a list of lights, the confirm dialog windows is execute before my selection command. But I would like the `confirmDialog` in order for user to see if every light we need are highlight in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to see the new selection before the `confirmDialog` pops up? I think it technically is doing the selection before, it's likely some redraw issue. You can stick a `cmds.currentTime` command in between your select and `confirmDialog` so that it forces the viewport to redraw with the selections:

```
cmds.select(clear=True)
lightType =['aiAreaLight']
selLight=cmds.ls(lights=True, visible=True, type=lightType)
cmds.currentTime(cmds.currentTime(q=True))  # Force viewport to redraw.
cmds.select(selLight)

answer = cmds.confirmDialog()
```